# What is the location of the 'about' information of a Github repository when is downloaded as ZIP file?

Tags: github

As known, all Github repositories have an associated 'about' information. But when I download the repository as a zip file I cannot find this information anywhere in the dowloaded directory.

Where it is located?

[image]